# how to uglify javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, class, gulp-uglify

I'm writing basic javascript using the [classes syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and trying to [uglify it with gulp](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify), but getting this error:

> events.js:72
>   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

I simply used the example code from mozilla's website:

```
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

And nothing special about my gulp file - works perfectly for any non-class js:

```
// Include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include Our Plugins
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});

// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/*.js', ['lint', 'scripts']);
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint', 'scripts', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Classes are only available in ECMAScript6; Are you sure your environment supports ES6?

Comment: to which environment are you referring? the code works as expected in my browser, and it passes the lint.

Comment: The env where you are running gulp

Comment: How would I verify this? I'm running ubuntu 14.04.3, nodejs v0.10.44, npm 3.8.5, gulp CLI 1.2.1 local 3.9.1, gulp-uglify 1.5.3

Comment: Jeff, it would be your node.js installation. See here: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @BrianDriscoll I finally figured out my Node environment was just fine because I didn't actually need Node to run ECMA6, the problem was the default branch used inside gulp-uglify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time, I resolved this with a workaround by [transpiling to ECMA 5 with Babel](https://github.com/DanWahlin/ES6Samples).

Later I discovered it was not a problem with my Node environment as the comments led me to believe, but in fact it was because [the default uglify branch used in gulp-uglify doesn't support ECMA 6 yet](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/issues/173#issuecomment-207004243).

The correct solution was to instead use the [`harmony` branch of UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony) or to use the npm wrapper [uglify-js-harmony](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-harmony).

Comment: Found that was deprecated and instead used gulp-uglify-es.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es