# How to solve this minification error on Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm getting below error running this command

```
gulp.task('minify', function () {
    return gulp
      .src('public/app/js/myapp.bundle.js')
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app/js/myapp.bundle.min.js'));
});
```

> GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript                                                                                      Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (MenuItem) (line: 1628, col: 18, pos: 53569)

Code on that location is this

```
 setters: [],
 execute: function () {
     class MenuItem {  // <-- line 1628
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to uglify javascript classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482076/how-to-uglify-javascript-classes)

Comment: TL;DR - `class` keyword is the problem

Answer (score 69, accepted):

UglifyJS [does not currently support](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/448) EcmaScript 6 structures [like classes](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/659).

You'll probably need to run your JavaScript through a transpiler step first, or find a minifier that knows what to do with ES6 code.

#### Update 2017-06-17

The branch of UglifyJS that is designed to work with ES6 is now published as [`uglify-es`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) on npm.

#### Update 2018-09-10

[`terser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser) is the new `uglify-es`, [`uglify-es` is no longer maintained](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/3156#issuecomment-392943058).

If using [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/) both [npmjs gulp-uglify-es](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es) and [npmjs gulp-terser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-terser) packages support terser.

```
npm install gulp-terser --save-dev
```

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const terser = require('gulp-terser');
 
function es(){
  return gulp.src('./src/index.js')
    .pipe(terser())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
}

gulp.task('default', es);
```

Comment: UglifyJS should get updated then. It seems like a fair amount of people use this and would use this especially if there were one less step.

Comment: @SMT: Agreed. And I get the impression they've been working on it. They've got a "harmony" version published as `uglify-es` now, which ditches some backwards API compatibility in favor of supporting ES6.

Comment: yeah i subscribed to one github issue in particular in that repo which is about this. still an ongoing discussion and not resolved yet @StriplingWarrior. Part of me just wants to be snarky and point out Sputnik 1 took 3 years to design and create and launch, yet 3 years isnt enough time to add in ES6 support for minification. :/

Answer (score 6):

If you run into this problem and you *have* in fact a transpiler step like Babel, make sure that you include the proper Babel preset in you `.babelrc` file. Otherwise Babel will simply leave your code as is.

E.g.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? What exactly should be included in the `.babelrc` file?

Comment: I've added an example