# How to pipe input to uglify-js-harmony in gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-uglify

I want to uglify some JS containing classes. This is not supported by `gulp-uglify` at the moment as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886840/how-to-solve-this-minification-error-on-gulp).

I have done . .

`npm install uglify-js-harmony --save-dev`

as advised in the previous answer, but being new to front end dev in general, I now don't know how to pipe my source through this as I could with `gulp-uglify`.

I have something like this . .

```
var uglify = require('uglify-js-harmony');

// ...

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(bower().concat(jsFiles))            
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'))
        .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
});
```

... but it bails saying `[17:42:40] TypeError: uglify is not a function`, and I'm at a loss on how to proceed. Thanks.

Comment: uglify-js-harmony looks like a convoluted tool that's only meant to be used on the command line. I don't think it's going to be easy to use here. I would probably pipe through babel instead.

Comment: @AndyRay please tell me more

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel

Answer (score -1):

It is much easier to just use regular `gulp-babel` in combination with `gulp-uglify` . .

`$ npm install --save-dev gulp-uglify gulp-babel babel-preset-es2015`

Then . . .

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    babel  = require('gulp-babel');


// ...

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    return gulp.src(//... src stuff
        .pipe(babel({ presets: ['es2015']}))
        .pipe(uglify()))
        //... other stuff
});
```

Comment: It is much easier, yes, but the regular uglify doesn't understand ES6+ syntax like `for await`, `@decorators` and so on.