# GulpUglifyError:Unable to minify JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am trying to minify my script files for which i am using gulp task runner 
And I am trying gulp-uglify plugin

Code:

```
 gulp.task('concat', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
        // .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

but i am getting error as

[image]

when i try to run gulp task as gulp concat
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve this minification error on Gulp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886840/how-to-solve-this-minification-error-on-gulp)

Answer (score 101):

The main error is generated when you're using ES6 format. Use the gulp-uglify-es module instead of 'gulp-uglify' to overcome this error.

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
```

Note: gulp-uglify-es is no longer being maintained. You may want to use `terser`/`gulp-terser` instead:

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-uglify-es'

Comment: @juFo did you install the package.
`npm install gulp-uglify-es --save-dev`

Answer (score 63):

To see the error in console:

```
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('concat', function() {
return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    // .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', function (err) { gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString()); })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

To find the **exact file, with line number** of error register and run this task:

```
var pump = require('pump');

gulp.task('uglify-error-debugging', function (cb) {
  pump([
    gulp.src('app/**/*.js'),
    uglify(),
    gulp.dest('./dist/')
  ], cb);
});
```

Comment: `pump` was a life saver to identify the one line in my code that had ES6 syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

I think the top answers here are not explaining how to get the error. The [docs](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/#errors) have a section on error handling:

> gulp-uglify emits an 'error' event if it is unable to minify a
>   specific file

So, just capture the error and do whatever you want with it (such as logging to console) to see the filename, line number, and additional info:

```
uglify().on('error', console.error)
```

or in a larger context:

```
gulp.task('foo', () => {

    return gulp.src([
        'asset/src/js/foo/*.js',
        'asset/src/js/bar/*.js',
    ])
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', console.error))
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));

});
```

This gives you a super helpful error!

```
{ GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
    at [stack trace])
  cause:
   { SyntaxError: Continue not inside a loop or switch
       [stack trace]
     message: 'Continue not inside a loop or switch',
     filename: 'ProductForm.js',
     line: 301,
     col: 37,
     pos: 10331 },
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify',
  fileName:
   '/asset/src/js/foo/ProductForm.js',
  showStack: false }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The error wasn't even coming from the file I was saving! Thank you!

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Comment: This helped me recover the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator «>»` because it doesn't know how to handle arrow functions yet :) thanks :)

Comment: this one not giving me this helpful error. still i get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274224/error-from-uglify-in-compress-task-error-in-plugin-gulp-uglify

Answer (score 15):

Have you used ES6 format in your script file?
If so try ES5 now because when you do gulp-uglify it doesnt understand ES6 format as of now 
and after that try your code

```
 gulp.task('concat', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

and run the task `gulp concat` it will work

Comment: I suddenly ran into this error and had no clue until I see your mentioning of ES5 vs ES6, and realize I did copy&paste some code like "() =>" and once I revert it to ES5 function, it works again. Thanks!

Comment: it really is quite a bummer. this has been an open issue on github for 3 years. uglify should be able to handle ES6, we shouldn't have to transpile fat arrow functions just for minification purposes.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was a deprecated option "preserveComments" that generated the error (and completely crashed the script).

Found the issue using:

```
gulp.task('concat', function() {
return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', function (err) { console.log( err ) })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var minifyJS = require('gulp-minify');

gulp.task('concat', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(minifyJS())
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The main error  to Unable to minifies JavaScript is the path not found. You can use the task usemin For this you need:

```
$ sudo npm install gulp-usemin --save-dev
$ sudo npm install gulp-livereload --save-dev
$ sudo npm install gulp-util --save-dev
```

and requires :

```
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var gutil = require('gulp-util'); //gutil for error display

gulp.task('usemin',['jshint'], function(){
    return gulp.src('./app/index.html')
    .pipe(usemin({
        css: [minifycss(),rev()],
        scripts: [uglify().on('error', function(err) {gutil.log(gutil.colors.red('[Error]'), err.toString());this.emit('end');}),rev()]
    })) 
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

Change the js: [uglify(), rev()] to scripts: [uglify(), rev()]
```

Answer (score 1):

you may have syntax error or used ES6 syntax. you can try https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/ firstly.