# Error from uglify in compress task Error in plugin 'gulp-uglify'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, build, gulp

```
[12:20:17] Finished 'images' after 12 s
Error from uglify in compress task Error in plugin 'gulp-uglify'
Message:
    D:\projects\Source\app\scripts\vendor.js: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword (default)
Details:
    fileName: D:\projects\Source\app\scripts\vendor.js
    lineNumber: 96908
[12:23:39] Finished 'fonts' after 3.55 min
[12:23:49] Finished 'jshint' after 3.75 min
```

I am getting above error on gulp Build. so far i have tried all solutions of [GulpUglifyError:Unable to minify JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521506/gulpuglifyerrorunable-to-minify-javascript) to no success. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify#using-a-different-uglifyjs) with [`uglifyes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-es) or use Babel or (if you use it) TypeScript to output to ES5.

Make sure to read the documentation more closely.

Example:

```js
var uglifyes = require('uglify-es'); // for ES support
var composer = require('gulp-uglify/composer'); // for using a different uglify runtime/config

var uglify = composer(uglifyes, console); // setup the new uglify constant

function javascriptTask ( done ) {

    gulp.src("[[file location]]")
        // [pipe processing]
        .pipe(uglify())
    done(); // this tells Gulp 4 that the task is done
    
}

let main = gulp.[series | parallel](javascriptTask); // edit out series or parallel depending on needs

export default = main // allows you launch all tasks in the gulp.[series | parallel] from the terminal with gulp
```

You can also use [`gulp-terser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-terser)

#### For transpiling

For a babel solution: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44958306)

If you use TypeScript you should have `target : 'es5'` in your `.tsconfig`, `tsify` (for `browserify`) or `gulp-typescript` object.