# Why gulp-uglify is not working when I used ES6 syntax in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, gulp

I'm trying to minify all of my AngularJS files to be compressed with `gulp-uglify`. But the problem is I've used ES6 syntax in my project, especially `arrow function`.

When I minify js file with as follow:

```
gulp.task('minify-scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(jsFiles)
    .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest))
    .pipe(rename('scripts.min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(jsDest));
});
```

for following ES6 code:

```
 apiService.fetchAccessToken($scope.body).then((response) => {
```

encountered following error:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

But when I reversed ES6 code to traditional code:

```
 apiService.fetchAccessToken($scope.body).then(function(response) {
```

Everything is working fine. Please let me know what I've missed to configure something inside **gulp** to minify `es6` code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to minify ES6 functions with gulp-uglify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958216/how-to-minify-es6-functions-with-gulp-uglify)

Comment: You may try to follow [this thread](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/659). I think this issue was with older versions. Can you verify?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [github README](https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify/blob/master/README.md#user-content-using-a-different-uglifyjs) of gulp-uglify, you should use uglify-es for ES6 support.

> // can be a git checkout // or another module (such as `uglify-es` for ES6 support)